# ASP.NET website not working properly in mobile

Tags: asp.net, mobile, wap

I have created a simple app with a page having a server side form, three fields and a button that submits and performs two operations - 1) adds the form fields to the database table 2) sends an email. Now everything works fine on the web browser on my machine but when I access the app through my mobile, the page does not seem to work. the UI and all are set but the button click functionality doesnt seem to be working and also the label which is set after a successful submit is already visible and showing the "thank you" message. Am i doing something wrong here?

I have checked the app on Nokia Smartphone browser, android phone, and iphone simulator.

Answer (score 0):

1st i would try to access the site from a different computer or through a proxy.  Just to make sure things work out well in different browsers.  That may catch your bug.  It may be working fine on your PC Locally, on a local web server, but may not be uploaded to the web.

Next, I would check to see if the devices you are using support Javascript.  Chances are good that your script relies on it.

Comment: I have checked on more than one machines, its working fine on the web browser. I am using normal web controls on the form... asp:Textbox controls and asp:Button. I hope thats not causing any issue?

Comment: can you do a simple test to make sure that the devices support javascript.  ASP.net should fall back to a no js version, but it may be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use [**`JQuery Mobile`**](http://jquerymobile.com/), it create Mobile friendly interface for your website. and for sure it work the same for each cell phone, but as Asp.net isnot easy to render for most of (old) phones, so that you're not able to use whatever you like.